# Deduplicate array of arrays whilst transforming items at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
    ["01/07", 1, 13],
    ["02/07", 0, 16],
    ["03/07", 0, 5],
    ["01/07", 2, 0],
    ["02/07", 2, 0],
    ["03/07", 12, 0],
    ["04/07", 12, 0],
    ["05/07", 9, 0]
]
```

I would like to join the rows when there are 2 equal dates and sum the 2 numeric values,
using the example above the result would be:

```
[
    ["01/07", 3, 13],
    ["02/07", 2, 16],
    ["03/07", 12, 5],
    ["04/07", 12, 0],
    ["05/07", 9, 0]
]
```

What would be the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Also please show an attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: @Taplar yes, it might happen that both values are non-zeros. Will post an attempt in a couple of minutes

Comment: @Taplar I've edited the example to show the result in the case of a value in both entries. It should be the sum of the 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `.reduce`:

```js
const joined = data.reduce((joined, [date, a, b]) => {
  const match = joined.find(([dateB]) => dateB == date);
  match ? (match[1] += a) && (match[2] += b) : joined.push([date, a, b]);
  return joined;
}, []);
```

Here's a live example:

```js
'use strict';

const data = [
  ["01/07", 1, 13],
  ["02/07", 0, 16],
  ["03/07", 0, 5],
  ["01/07", 2, 0],
  ["02/07", 2, 0],
  ["03/07", 12, 0],
  ["04/07", 12, 0],
  ["05/07", 9, 0]
];

const joined = data.reduce((joined, [date, a, b]) => {
  const match = joined.find(([dateB]) => dateB == date);
  match ? (match[1] += a) && (match[2] += b) : joined.push([date, a, b]);
  return joined;
}, []);

console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const collaspsedArray = jsArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
const index = acc.findIndex(x => x[0] === el[0])
if (index === -1) {
    acc.push(el)
    return acc
}
for (let i = 1; i < acc[index].length; i++) {
    acc[index][i] += el[i]
}
return acc
}, [])
```

I like this way

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#reduce` and a map to group entries by date. When adding to the map sum the numbers, then export the values with `Object.values`:

```js
const unique_sum = xs =>
  Object.values(
    xs.reduce((acc, [date, a, b]) => {
      const [, aa=0, bb=0] = acc[date] || [];
      acc[date] = [date, a + aa, b + bb];
      return acc;
    }, {}));
    
    
console.log(unique_sum(data));
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
    ["01/07", 1, 13],
    ["02/07", 0, 16],
    ["03/07", 0, 5],
    ["01/07", 2, 0],
    ["02/07", 2, 0],
    ["03/07", 12, 0],
    ["04/07", 12, 0],
    ["05/07", 9, 0]
];
</script>
```